# What is the right hand side in this definition of $n$-dimensional cross product

Tags: definition, multilinear-algebra

Let ${\bf e_1}, \dots, {\bf e_n}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let 
${\bf w_1} = (w_{11},\dots,w_{1n}), \dots, {\bf w_{n-1}}=(w_{n-1\;1},\dots,w_{n-1\;n}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then one can define

$${\bf w_1} \times {\bf w_2} \times \cdots \times {\bf w_{n-1}} = \begin{vmatrix} {\bf e_1} & {\bf e_2} & \cdots & {\bf e_n} \cr w_{11} & w_{12} & \cdots & w_{1n} \cr \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \cr w_{n-1\;1} & w_{n-1\;2} & \cdots & w_{n-1\;n} \end{vmatrix}$$

see e.g. [Wikiepdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra).

> The problem I have is: if the right hand side denotes determinant then
>   this is calculating the determinant of a non square matrix and I don't
>   know how this is defined. (Note the dimensions are $(n+(n-1))\times n = (2n-1) \times n$
>
> How is the determinant for non square matrices defined?

Comment: This is actually a n x n matrix. Note that the first row is e_1,e_2,...,e_n and there are n-1 rows that follow in the form of w_11, w_21, ... ,w_(n-1)1

Comment: @Ethan: Since the $e_k$ are $n \times 1$ vectors, the above matrix is as the OP described above.

Comment: @Ethan I don't understand what you mean: $\mathbf{e_1}$ has $n$-entries (down) followed by $n-1$ entries as you point out. Altogether $n + n-1$ entries. ?

Comment: _Symbolically_, it is an $n\times n$ matrix. Don't expand the $\vec{e}_i$ into coordinates. Just take the determinant according to however you normally do so, and whenever multiplication involves the scalars form below, multiply accordingly, and when it involves a scalar times one of these vectors from the top row, multiply the scalar times the vector accordingly.

Comment: @alex.jordan Heh, I had no idea that this was the intended meaning of this! Thank you, I will try an example using this idea and see if I can work it out.

Comment: @alex.jordan Please post your comment as an answer, I think it will turn out to perfectly answer my question.

Comment: @astudent: I have given a formal definition below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolically, it is an $n\times n$ matrix. Don't expand the $\vec{e}_i$ into coordinates. Just take the determinant according to however you normally do so, and whenever multiplication involves the scalars from below, multiply accordingly, and when it involves a scalar times one of these vectors from the top row, multiply the scalar times the vector accordingly.

---

Also, I don't think it's helpful to think that $\vec{e}_i=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Sometimes that is what is meant, but consider this: just let the collection of $\vec{e}_i$ be abstract vectors. Then, for example if there are only $2$ of these, when you see $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, that is just code for $1\vec{e}_1+0\vec{e}_2$.  So $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ isn't *exactly* the same as $\vec{e}_1$; rather, $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is the coordinate vector for $\vec{e}_1$ with respect to the basis $\{\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2\}$.

I find this more helpful than oversimplifying to $\vec{e}_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. It may feel strange, but that is because in earlier math classes you worked with coordinates form the start instead of pure vectors. If that point that is one unit to the right of the origin had always been just called $\vec{e}_1$ instead of $(1,0)$, what I am describing would feel more natural.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent definition is the unique element ${w_1} \times {w_2} \times \cdots \times {w_{n-1}}$ such that
$\langle x, {w_1} \times {w_2} \times \cdots \times {w_{n-1}} \rangle = \det\begin{bmatrix} {x_1} & {x_2} & \cdots & {x_n} \cr w_{11} & w_{12} & \cdots & w_{1n} \cr \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \cr w_{n-1\;1} & w_{n-1\;2} & \cdots & w_{n-1\;n} \end{bmatrix}$ for all $x$.

This avoids taking determinants with vectors as elements.

To **define** the quantity in the question, we let
$\det\begin{bmatrix} {e_1} & {e_2} & \cdots & {e_n} \cr w_{11} & w_{12} & \cdots & w_{1n} \cr \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \cr w_{n-1\;1} & w_{n-1\;2} & \cdots & w_{n-1\;n} \end{bmatrix} = \sum_k \langle e_k, {w_1} \times {w_2} \times \cdots \times {w_{n-1}} \rangle e_k$.

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to understand this particular definition in my question.

Comment: Well, the definition in the question is best understood as follows: The right hand side above defines a polynomial in $x_k, w_{ij}$. This can be written uniquely as $\sum_k x_k p_k(w1,...,w_n-1)$. Then the object in the question is **defined** as $\sum_k e_k p_k(w1,...,w_n-1)$ (that is, the variable $x_k$ is replaced by the vector $e_k$).

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to think about the definition is to evaluate the determinant symbolically to get some large (polynomial) expression in the variables. Then replace the $x_k$ variables by the vectors $e_k$.